# Find the upper bound of the error for the approximation of $\int_{x_1}^{x_2}\cos(x)$

Tags: numerical-methods, solution-verification, numerical-calculus, simpsons-rule

> Consider $f(x) = \cos(x)$ and the points $x_0 = \pi/2$, $x_1 = \pi/4$
> and $x_2=3\pi/4$. Consider $f(x_i)$ with 5 decimal places. Find an
> estimate for the error of integration when you use Simpson's rule to
> calculate the integral of f between $x_1$ and $x_2$.

I did

$$E(f) < |\frac{b-a}{180}||\frac{b-a}{N}|\max_{[x_1,x_2]} |f^{(4)}| =  0.0023479$$

Is this correct?

Is the reason I am given 3 points that I need an even number of intervals to use Simpsons rule and is that why I set N = 2 and not 1?

Comment: This is kind of a strange question: $\cos x$ is anti-symmetric across $x=\pi/2$ on the interval $[\pi/4,3\pi/4]$, so both the integral and any balanced numerical evaluation of it will be exactly $0$.

Comment: @BarryCipra What about the error?

Comment: When the "approximation" gives the exact value, the error is $0$. I'm afraid that's about all I can say here. I assume this is a homework problem of some sort, but I'm perplexed as to what the problem poser is looking for, unless it's intended as a trick question.

Comment: @BarryCipra It's a possibility. I'll ask my prof. Thanks